# dplyr Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '.' not found

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to manipulate this bit of data with dplyr using the code below, but I keep getting the error.

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '.' not found
```

The code I'm using, I think it's something to do with referencing the columns by index rather than name.

```
closing <- filter(survey, .[[47]] != 0, .[[48]] >= 10) %>%
  mutate(percieved_jobs = .[[47]] * 12, percieved_actual_jobs = (.[[47]] * 12) * (.[[48]] / 100)) %>%
  group_by(listing) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), mean_closing = mean(.[[48]]), mean_pjobs = mean(percieved_jobs), mean_jobs = mean(percieved_actual_jobs))
```

Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the error simply comes from your way of using the piping in the first command. The `.` (dot) refers to the previous result in the pipeline but there is nothing before your `filter` so it gives the error!

To get it work you can take the data.frame out of the filter function:

```
closing <- survey %>% filter(.[[47]] != 0, .[[48]] >= 10) %>% ...
```

I tested it with another dataset.